# How to get element data within click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, jquery-data

Is there a tidier/easier way of getting the checkbox element's 'catNum' value when in its click() function?

```
function createCategoriesList() {

var catNames = new Array("First cat", "Second cat", "Third cat");
var catImageURLs = new Array("First.png", "Second.png", "Third.png");

jQuery('<ul/>', {
    id: 'map-cats'
}).appendTo('#map-controls');

for(var i = 0; i < catNames.length; i++ ) {

    var listItem = jQuery('<li/>').appendTo('#map-cats');

    jQuery('<img/>', {
        src: catImageURLs[i],
        alt: ''

    }).appendTo(listItem);

    var checkbox = jQuery('<input/>', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        checked: 'checked',
        id: 'cat_' + i,
        name: 'cat_' + i

    }).appendTo(listItem);
    checkbox.data("catNum", i);

    checkbox.click(function() {
        //alert("The cat num selected is: " + this.data("catNum")); //throws exception
        alert("The cat num selected is: " + jQuery('#' + this.id).data('catNum')); //works but there must be a better way??
    });

    jQuery('<label/>', {
        htmlFor: catImageURLs[i],
        text: catNames[i],
        for: 'cat_' + i

    }).appendTo(listItem);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element that comes into the `click` function is a raw DOM object, not a jQuery object, so in order to use jQuery methods on it, we have to pass it through jQuery first. This is why `this.data("catNum")` doesn't work in your example code.

But the `jQuery()` function can accept DOM objects as well as selector strings, so instead of

```
jQuery('#' + this.id)
```

you can just use

```
jQuery(this)
```

Which as you wanted, a lot tidier.

Alternatively, you can use `this` as a raw DOM object, but you'd need to use the DOM methods with it rather than the jQuery methods:

```
this.dataset.catNum      //for modern HTML5 browsers.
```

or

```
this.getAttribute("data-catNum")   //works in all browsers
```

Answer (score 4):

```
checkbox.click(function() {
    alert("The cat num selected is: " + jQuery(this).data('catNum'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. Sorry for more extensive answer than asked / I planned. Might have typos but seems to work [at js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lxrk/):

```
$(function(){
    createCategoriesList();
});

function createCategoriesList() {
    var catNames = new Array("First cat", "Second cat", "Third cat");
    var catImageURLs = new Array("First.png", "Second.png", "Third.png");

    var output = '<ul id="map-cats">';
    $.each(catNames, function(i, v) {
      output += '<li>';
      output += '<label for="cat_'+i+'">'+v+'</label>';
      output += '<input type="checkbox" id="cat_'+i+'" name="cat_'+i+'" data-catnum="'+i+'" />';
      output += '<img src="'+catImageURLs[i]+'" alt="" title="" />';
      output += '</li>';
    });
    output += '</ul>';
    $("#map-controls").html(output);
    $("#map-cats").on("click", "input",  function(){
        alert($(this).data("catnum"));
    });
}
```